# How to filter docker client environment variables into a docker run command?

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

Suppose on my docker client machine I have the following environment variables:

```
myValA=B
DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_C=networksettingD
myValE=F
DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_G=arbitrarySettingH
```

and I want to pass two of these values into my Docker container I'm running. (The ones containing `DOCKER_CONTAINER`).

Now I could manually hardcode it, like this:

```
docker run -e DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_C='networksettingD' -e DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_G='arbitrarySettingH' --name container_name dockerhub_id/image_name
```

But I want to automate this process.

Something like:

```
docker run -e ${env | grep "DOCKER_CONTAINER"} ...
```

My question is: **How to filter docker client environment variables into a docker run command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
set | grep DOCKER_CONTAINER > env_file
docker run --env-file env_file ...
```

Or if you really want a single command line:

```
docker run --env-file <(set | grep DOCKER_CONTAINER) ...
```

The `<(...)` construct is bash syntax for process substitution.  From
`bash(1)`:

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs)  or  the
>   /dev/fd  method  of  naming open files.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The
>   process list is run with its input or output connected to  a  FIFO  or  some  file  in
>   /dev/fd.  The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command as the
>   result of the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
env | { sed -n '/DOCKER/s/^/-e /p' ; echo myimage; } | xargs docker run
```

Comment: This actually won't work.  If your final command is `xargs docker run myimage`, the result from xargs will be `docker run myimage -e ...`, which won't do what you want. Also, variables containing whitespace would trip this up in any case, and if you were hoping to have an interactive docker session you would be out of luck.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the feedback. I don't actually use docker, but I have amended my answer to account for the fact that further arguments may follow the `-e` options.

Comment: This will still fail because `xargs` passes `-e DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_C=networksettingD -e DOCKER_CONTAINER_VALUE_G=arbitrarySettingH` as a single argument, resulting in an error.

Comment: @larsks Third time lucky?

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like:

```
docker run -e $(set | echo $(sed -n "/^DOC.*_CON.*_VAL.*/s/^/-e /p")" ")--name container_name dockerhub_id/image_name
```

- $( ) --  run command
- set -- list environment variables
- sed -n -- do no print
- match string ^DOC.*_CON.*_VAL.*
- substitute "-e " for the beginning of line character
- p -- print matches
- " " -- add space between results

You can include the full match string; I usually just go for the shortest...

Verified this works.